# Disable line numbers but allow them in prog-mode and text-mode

Tags: emacs, line-numbers

I would like to disable the line numbers in Emacs because having them in Org-mode, terminal, mu4e, elfeed, etc.. looks ugly.

So I removed this:

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode t)
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to enable the line numbers only for `prog-mode` and eventually plain text files (but not Org), I think that's `text-mode`.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
  (dolist (mode '(text-mode-hook
                  prog-mode-hook
                  conf-mode-hook))
    (add-hook mode (lambda () (display-line-numbers-mode 1))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to just enable them for corresponding modes using hooks.  The hook need to call `display-line-numbers-mode` with `1` as argument to enable this mode.  I personally prefer to put code for the hook into a separate function, that could be redefined at any point of time if necessary, something like this (this hook will be called when entering file with most of programming modes):

```
(defun my-display-numbers-hook ()
  (display-line-numbers-mode 1)
  )
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-display-numbers-hook)
```

Similarly you can do it for `text-mode` - it will enable for all `text-mode`-based files:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-display-numbers-hook)
```

Comment: `text-hook` should be `text-mode-hook`, and as `org-mode` derives from `text-mode` this will enable line numbers for org-mode.  You can disable them again in `org-mode-hook`, or else add conditional logic to the function for enabling them (you can test `major-mode`).

Comment: Yes, thank you @phils - I didn’t copy code but entered it manually and made mistake. I’ve changed that

Comment: @ZoltanKing `(display-line-numbers-mode t)` works, but is not best practice.  Per the docstring (and as for any minor mode) the argument should be a positive number (traditionally 1): `(display-line-numbers-mode 1)`

Comment: I’m old timer, having habit for t

Comment: The main problem with using `t` to enable is that it suggests that you would use `nil` to disable, which is incorrect -- `nil` also enables unconditionally (and even in the past it used to toggle rather than disable).  It's fine if you know, but I think suggesting the use of `t` in S.E. answers is liable to trip up readers later on.

Comment: Alex Ott- I updated my post. Can you please take a look at the end of the post. There is a code block. Do you think the code I use with `dolist` is okay? It activates line numbers for three modes.

Comment: that's ok, but notice the sentence that I wrote: "I personally prefer to put code for the hook into a separate function, that could be redefined at any point of time if necessary" - the main reason that for every `dolist` execution, the new lambda will be generated, so it won't be easy to remove this lambda from list of hooks, compared to the use of the named function...